# How do I center a value surrounded by CardActions (material ui)

Tags: css, material-ui

So I'm having this issue, this is an image of my site

[image]

And this is code.

```
<CardActions>
   <Typography
     style={{
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     color: 'red',
    }}
    >
    {product.price}đ  ///// the price number /////
   </Typography>
</CardActions>
```

I want my price tag to be at the center of the card (similar to the sold button underneath), at first I tried to wrap it in `<Box>` element then add `textAlign` to it, no success there.

This seems like a simple issue to solve but I think I'm misunderstanding something here, I've tried many ways but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the price you try just add a in-line style like below

```js
<CardActions>
  <Typography
    style={{
      fontWeight: "bold",
      color: "red",
      margin: "0px auto"
    }}
  >
    123 d
  </Typography>
</CardActions>
```

encourage me with a up-vote when it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `Typography` component has an [`align`](https://mui.com/api/typography/#:%7E:text=Description-,align) property which you can set to `center`.

Comment: you mean like this `style={{ align: 'center' }}`? I did try that, wasn't successful

Comment: @gem173 no, not in the style, it's actually a prop. `<Typography align={'center'} style={{...}}>`.

Comment: oh my bad, well I did try like what you said but it didn't work, still thank you for your trouble.